# ImagesLoaded with Masonry, Object #<Object> has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, frontend

Getting this error, trying to use Masonry with imageLoaded:

> "Object # has no method 'imagesLoaded'"

The links to the necessary scripts are in my header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is how the code looks in my footer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#archive-post-container').imagesLoaded(function() {
        $(this).masonry({
            itemSelector : '.post',
            columnWidth:344
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT / ADDENDUM:
Placing the script tags for ImagesLoaded and Masonry in the actual .php file for the page I need them on, instead of in header.php gets me this error instead, coming from ImagesLoaded:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Not sure why moving the tags just from the to just under the header would change this, but at least now I am getting to imagesLoaded?

Comment: make sure you path to the imagesloaded script is correct and the file is loaded

Comment: I'm not getting any 404s for the scripts, and they are visible in the Chrome dev tools after the page loads.

Comment: Odd. if I place the <script> tags for Masonry and ImagesLoaded at the top of the actual php file for the page I want to use, instead of in header.php, I get the error "uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" instead of the original error, and it comes from ImagesLoaded. Not sure why imagesLoaded is only being found when I put it here, or now what this error is.

Answer (score 19):

Note that ImagesLoaded is no longer included in the latest Masonry distribution, per

http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v2

You can get it directly here:

http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/

Comment: Why is this? Why don't they remove it from the docs? At least they could say how to get it...

Comment: I guess you get what you pay for :-)